# Find the 42th number which sum of its digits is 42

Tags: objective-c

I've got another interesing programming/mathematical problem.
I want to write an application, find the 42th number which sum of its digits is 42, i need find number which have sum of its digits is 42 and add to new array to print the 42th number in new array which have about 50 numbers have sum of its digits is 42. Thank you for taking the time to help.

@implementation AppDelegate

```
static NSArray *newArray ;
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification
{


    int numberWithSum42;
    for (int i=69999;i<80000;i++)
    {
        int x=[self findTotalNumber:i];

        if(x==12){
             numberWithSum42=i;
            newArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[NSNumber numberWithInt:numberWithSum42], nil];
        }
        NSLog(@"%@",newArray);
    }
    [self print42ndVariable];
}
-(void)print42ndVariable{
    int j;
    int count = (int)[newArray count];
    for (j = 0; j < count; j++){
        NSLog (@"42nd variable of array   = %@", [newArray objectAtIndex: 42]);
    }

}
-(int)findTotalNumber:(int) n{
    int s=0;
    while (n>0)
    {
        int k=n%10;
        s=s+k;
        n=n/10;
    }
    NSLog(@"%i",s);
    return n;
}
```

@end

Comment: What's wrong with the code you have now?

Comment: i can't add the number which have sum of its digits is 42 to new array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification{
int requiredNumber;
int currentIndex;
int sumOfDigits;

//Assuming the limits you wnat are 69000<=x<80000

for (int i=69999;i<80000;i++)
{
    sumOfDigits= [self sum:i];

    if(i==42){
         currentIndex++;
    }
    if (currentIndex == 42){
         NSLog(i); //The number!
    }
}

}
-(void)sum:(int)number{
int digit,sum=0, temp;
    temp = number;

    while(temp > 0) {
        digit = temp%10;
        sum += digit;
        temp = temp/10;
    }
    NSLog(@"Sum of digits of %i = %i",number,sum);
    return sum;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you want all the numbers + print 42nd number.

```
 static NSMutableArray * numberArray ;
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification
{

numberArray = [NSMutableArray array];
int exitJ;
for (int i=69999;i<80000;i++)
{
    int x=[self findTotalNumber:i];

    if(x==42){//You want the sum to be 42 and not 12??

         exitJ++;
        [numberArray addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:i]];
    }
    if(exitJ>=42)break; //Exit after getting 42 numbers

  }
  NSLog(@"%@", numberArray);
  [self print42ndVariable];
}
```

The numberArray should have 42 numbers.